# tengo un problema en mi codigo el cual en consola me salta ReferenceError: appproductod is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

bueno la cosa es de que tengo el siguiente codigo

```
var app=new Vue({
   el:"#slider",
   data:{
      productos:[]
   },
   created:function(){
   this.datoss();
   },
   methods:{
      datoss:function(){  

         fetch(`Private/Modulos/inicio/procesos.php?proceso=recibirDatos&miproducto=${JSON.stringify(this.productos )}`).then( resp=>resp.json() ).then(resp=>{ 
            this.productos = resp;         
         });

      }    ,
      verProd(info){
      appproductod.productosd=info;
         console.log(appproductod);

      }   

   }

   }
```

)

lo cual tengo problema con el metodo de verprod el cual le intento pasar los datos del index.html por medio (info) pero.. el error viene en que appproductod, en consola me dice: ReferenceError: appproductod is not defined y esa variable la tengo definida en un archivo js diferente el cual esta asi:

```
var appproductod = new Vue({
    el:"#productovista",
    data:{
       productosd:[]
    }, created:function(){

    }
    ,methods:{
        todo:function(){


         }
    }

    })
```

no se que estoy haciendo mal

Comment: Debes visitar **con urgencia** [el centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help), específicamente [¿ Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta ?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Colocar el código como texto y no como imágenes, un título descriptivo, ... Un saludo.

Comment: Considera revisa [ask] y modifica tu pregunta, **el còdigo agregalo como texto ya que  no es legible** ,saludos.

Comment: ok lo deje en texto :)

Comment: Asegurate de que tu variable appproductod este declarada antes de usarla.

Comment: la variable si esta declarada en un archivo js distinto en el texto el segundo código esta en otro archivo js y en el primer código lo llamo para asignarle los datos y es ahí donde no se la razón que me salte el mensaje

Comment: Importaste tu variable en el otro archivo??

Comment: mmm nop, ya que esa forma me a funcionado en otras pantallas codificado de igual manera, el cual declaro la variable en un archivo js con su data que tiene una variable para asignarle los datos de otra pantalla  

tipo: tengo un home con items y al clickear un item en el metodo verprod en la variable info se asignan los datos y poniendo el nombre de la otra bariable con su data mandarle esos datos, ya he hecho otras pantallas con esa forma y me ha funcionado